# Do I need to open and close the connection every time the schema changes?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I read a few times that I need to open and close the connection to the database when the schema changes when using FMDB. However, the following works fine:

```
FMDatabase *derp = [self getDefaultDatabase]; // custom function that returns open db
[derp executeUpdate:@"create table `derping` (`id` int, `time_stamp` datetime, primary key (id))"];
[derp executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO derping (id) VALUES (123)"];
FMResultSet *derping = [derp executeQuery:@"select * from derping"];
[derping next];
NSLog(@"%@", [derping resultDictionary]);
```

Is this dangerous? Are there situations where it will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing should be OK - but if you alter a table, then you better be sure to close and then re-open the database handle.

Comment: So new tables will show up but altered tables won't be reflected?

Comment: (And maybe `closeOpenResultSets`.)